# How to align desktop icons with consistent icon sizes and short file names?

Tags: icons, desktop-environments

I find it very annoying that the icons on the desktop are not aligned in a proper grid.
The icon sizes are not consistent and longer file names are shown on multiple lines, this is just plain ugly and annoying if I have many items on the desktop.

Also, the `keep aligned` option doesn't help to align horizontally. Is there a way to override this, to have same icon size and limit the file name shown so that it looks perfectly aligned ?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

you can align/save/restore the desktop icons on 14.04 if you are using nautilus as your file manager ... There is a script/app to do this .. Just download Happy Desktop at gnomefiles.org. The script can align the desktop icons to a grid that you define by setting the number of icons per row and icons per column you would like for your desktop. You can fine tune the spacing by adjusting the left and top margins of the "grid" .. and you can fine tune the grid width/height to your liking.

The icon positions are then adjusted to the nearest grid points. It's free!